# Accessing user information in Express JS is returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

I am currently using Passport for authentication within my application. When trying to pull a users email in order to store in my db along with other information, I get a returned value of undefined. If I pull the entire user object I get the correct information though. See below.

Here is the server.js file initializing the session.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'sessionSecret'
})); 
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 
app.use(flash());
```

Here is the route information

```
app.get('/itemCreation', function (req, res) {
    res.render('itemCreation.ejs', {
        user: req.user 
    });
});
app.post('/itemCreation', function (req, res) {
    var item = new itemSchema();
    item.local.productName = req.body.productName;
    item.local.itemPrice = req.body.itemPrice;
    item.local.Quantity = req.body.Quantity;
    item.local.Description = req.body.Description;
    console.log(req.user.firstName);
    item.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        else
            console.log('Saved item information successfully');

    });
    res.redirect('/shop');
});
```

Here is my Item model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        productName     : String,
        itemPrice       : Number,
        Quantity        : Number,
        Description     : String
        }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('item', itemSchema);
```

[Here is the result of pulling the whole object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzMQr.png), which I get by calling

```
console.log(req.user);
```

[and here is the result of pulling just the email from the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzd4I.png), which I get by calling

```
console.log(req.user.email);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shoud be `console.log(req.user.local.email);`

Comment: Thank you! Overlooked that :)